# How to create a logarithmic scale for the x and y axis of a heat map with Python

Tags: python, heatmap, axis, logarithm, imshow

Im having some issues creating a heatmap using plt.imshow() with specific axes that I want to display in a logarithmic scale. I tried different methods, but the image doesn't seem to work when i try and set the axes to log scale.

I have a CSV data file from an experiment. The first row are the values for the x axis "Concentration" and the first column is the y axis "velocity". The rest of the data is a matrix with the measured values,  corresponding to the x and y axis. This is the matrix i want to visualise.

This is my method:

```
#upload data file
data = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv', header=None)

#transfer data to numpy array and get first column as y axis first row as x axis
def get_data_array(data):
    data_array= np.array(data)
    x_axis= data_array[0,1:]
    y_axis= data_array[1:,0]
    result_data = data_array[1:, 1:]
    return x_axis, y_axis,result_data

#get data
x_axis, y_axis, values = get_data_array(data)
```

I then want to visualise the values in a heat map using plt.imshow() and add the x axis and y axis to the image and set those to logarithmic scale.

```
matrix = np.array(values)
# Apply logarithmic transformation to the matrix
matrix_log = np.log(matrix)

# Create the heatmap using imshow with logarithmic scale
plt.imshow(matrix_log, cmap='YlOrRd', origin='lower')

# Set x and y axis labels
plt.xlabel('Concentration')
plt.ylabel('Velocity')

# Set x and y axis tick values and labels
plt.xticks(range(len(x_axis), x_axis)
plt.yticks(range(len(y_axis)), y_axis)

# Set x and y axis scales to logarithmic
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

# Add colorbar with logarithmic scale
cbar = plt.colorbar(format="%1.1e")
cbar.set_label('Colorbar Label')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()  # Invert the y-axis direction

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The axis are showing in log scale, but the image isn't showing. There is just a white block (I checked the values of the matrix there are no values =<0)
[Heat map with log scale axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVJ1r.png)

If i take out the plt.xscale('log') and plt.yscale('log') the image works its just that then it doesn't give me the x and y axis in logscale (i have adjusted the thicks a bit to bigger intervals just so you can read the numbers on the axis)

Can anyone give me any advice what i might be doing wrong or can do differently?

Comment: Hello,would you give sample data to test the results?

Comment: @Hamed_gibago not sure how to share data file on here?

Comment: it depends on file size. If It is a large file, please make it small and upload sample data file in file sharing sites such as https://wetransfer.com/ or share it on google drive.